# Why does my button group doesnt work and display?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, radio-button, buttongroup

I am learning and new to GUI and in this program used ECLIPSE IDE (drag and drop windows builder)

**I declared two radio buttons for Gender: Male and Female**

If its clicks to male or female button it should only (click one) and  go to that button and not both, so therefore I want it automatically the other one to be unselected to avoid duplicate selection

So I already did some research and `import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;` but I'm still  confused as to why it doesn't work because I can still click both of the radio buttons. *I think it has something to do with my panel?*

Why does it happen  and how can I fix it?

*Here is my program*

```
public AddRecord() {

    setUndecorated(true);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 1063, 640);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBounds(new Rectangle(5, 0, 0, 0));
    contentPane.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 240));
    contentPane.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 28), 1, true)); 
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);    
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);  
    
    JPanel pnlInfo = new JPanel();
    pnlInfo.setBounds(24, 20, 1015, 597);
    contentPane.add(pnlInfo);
    pnlInfo.setLayout(null);
    
    JLabel lblGender = new JLabel("Gender:");
    lblGender.setBounds(32, 174, 50, 10);
    pnlInfo.add(lblGender);
    lblGender.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    
    ButtonGroup btnBg = new ButtonGroup();  
    btnBg.add(rdbtnMale);
    btnBg.add(rdbtnFemale);     

    JRadioButton rdbtnMale  = new JRadioButton("Male");
    rdbtnMale.setBounds(79, 169, 55, 21);
    pnlInfo.add(rdbtnMale);

    JRadioButton rdbtnFemale = new JRadioButton("Female");
    rdbtnFemale.setBounds(136, 169, 76, 21);
    pnlInfo.add(rdbtnFemale); 
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). (Rather than an uncompilable code snippet - which possibly do not even contain the error.) 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: BTW - remove every `static` declaration. That usually adds to, rather than solves, problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not even compile,

move the lines

```
ButtonGroup btnBg = new ButtonGroup();  
btnBg.add(rdbtnMale);
btnBg.add(rdbtnFemale);
```

to the end of your code

like this

```
    setUndecorated(true);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 1063, 640);
    JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBounds(new Rectangle(5, 0, 0, 0));
    contentPane.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 240));
    contentPane.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 28), 1, true));
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JPanel pnlInfo = new JPanel();
    pnlInfo.setBounds(24, 20, 1015, 597);
    contentPane.add(pnlInfo);
    pnlInfo.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblGender = new JLabel("Gender:");
    lblGender.setBounds(32, 174, 50, 10);
    pnlInfo.add(lblGender);
    lblGender.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));


    JRadioButton rdbtnMale  = new JRadioButton("Male");
    rdbtnMale.setBounds(79, 169, 55, 21);
    pnlInfo.add(rdbtnMale);

    JRadioButton rdbtnFemale = new JRadioButton("Female");
    rdbtnFemale.setBounds(136, 169, 76, 21);
    pnlInfo.add(rdbtnFemale);

    ButtonGroup btnBg = new ButtonGroup();
    btnBg.add(rdbtnMale);
    btnBg.add(rdbtnFemale);
```